# Isometric, self-adjoint linear operator is unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification

$\newcommand{c}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $T : H \to H$ be a linear operator that is both isometric and self-adjoint. Is it true that $T$ is surjective (and hence unitary)?

My proof is as follows: Let $x \in H$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\|T^2(x) - x\| &= \c{T^2(x) - x,T^2(x) - x} \\
&= \c{T^2(x),T^2(x)} - \c{T^2(x),x} - \c{x,T^2(x)} + \c{x,x} \\
&= \c{x,x} - \c{T(x),T(x)} - \c{T(x),T(x)} + \c{x,x} \\
&= \c{x,x} - \c{x,x} - \c{x,x} + \c{x,x} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Therefore, $T^2(x) = x$, and in particular $T$ is surjective.

Is this proof correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does 'that is both isometric' mean? Do you mean  isometric and self-adjoin t? You seem to assume that $T=T^{*}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, it's as per what you said. I've corrected it.

Comment: What you have done is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy okay, thanks for the verification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct according to your definitions.

Unitary = Isometry + Surjectivity